# PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile: How to perform async operation on page transition

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

My main page has a link to another JQM page which holds a list of phones:

```
<a href="#phonesPage">Phones List</a>
```

The list of phones is cached in the app-preferences, using this plugin:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-preferences" spec="~0.99.3" />
```

Before showing the page, I need to populate the list of phones. Reading the preferences in an asynchronous operation:

```
var prefs = window.plugins.appPreferences;
prefs.fetch('phonesList').then(function(value) {
  console.log('got value='+JSON.stringify(value));
}, function(err) {
  console.log('got err='+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

I want to respond to *pagecontainerbeforeshow* event, like this:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function (event, ui) {
  var id = ui.toPage.get()[0].id;
  if (id === "phonesPage") {
    <!--read list from preferences, then populate list view in page -->
  }
```

So my problem is that I cannot block the execution of *pagecontainerbeforeshow* until the data is read from the preferences.

Is my approach wrong? Can anyone please suggest the right way to achieve this goal?

Comment: if you absolutely need to have the list populated before showing the page, then remove the anchor and navigate to the page by using `$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#phonesPage");`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I was actually setting the href to "#" so that the chevron icon will still appear

Comment: just to be clear: if you don't need the built-in navigation feature of JQM, in most cases instead of an `anchor` you can use an `input` button , they looks the same, see here: [Button markup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/button-markup/)